# Why can't I set the appearance of a selected item in UIPickerView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

I have a custom UIPickerView which I set the model of in my ViewController's ViewDidLoad method.

I'm able to set the appearance of each row item that appears in an override of GetView() for my PickerModel, like so:

```
 public override UIView GetView(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component, UIView view)
    {
        var selectedItem = pickerView.SelectedRowInComponent(0);

        UILabel lbl = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 0, 130f, 40f));
        lbl.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
        lbl.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12f);
        lbl.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        lbl.Text = _values[(int)row];

        if (row == selectedItem)
        {
            lbl.BackgroundColor = MyColours.GetBluish;
        }

        return lbl;
    }
```

But that if statement for setting the appearance of the currently selected item only fires for the first and last items in the picker. Why is this?

**A couple things to note**
My delegate and datasource are set to my model after setting the model variable in my ViewController. Is this how the delegate and datasource are supposed to work?
Other guides suggest overriding ViewForRow (ViewFor in Xamarin) in the UIPickerView subclass. But this override isn't getting called when I interact with the picker :(.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because UIPickerView calls `GetView` before the row is selected.

Override `Selected` instead, and update the current view:

```
public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
{
    var view = pickerView.ViewFor(row, component);
    view.BackgroundColor = Drive1Colours.GetBluish;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it won't update the UIPickerView as I scroll through it. It only updates when I release the picker

Comment: Also that call to 
            var view = picker.ViewFor(row, component); returns null.